# adding a UUID4 ID to each row in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I am inserting the result of a SELECT statement from a relational table into another table using Pentaho, is it possible to add a UUID4 identifier to each row and then insert.

Data before insertion :

```
ip              country city    start_time
1.7411624393E10 Canada  London  2017-06-01 15:27:23
1.7411221531E10 Canada  Ottawa  2017-06-02 23:57:56
1.846525287E9   Canada  Langley 2017-06-02 22:27:29
2.0647254234E10 Canada  Toronto 2017-06-02 22:22:49
2.0647254234E10 Canada  Toronto 2017-06-02 22:22:12
2.0647254234E10 Canada  Toronto 2017-06-02 22:21:20
```

Needed as :

```
UUID ip             country city    start_time
ID1  1.7411624393E10    Canada  London  2017-06-01 15:27:23
ID2  1.7411221531E10    Canada  Ottawa  2017-06-02 23:57:56
ID3  1.846525287E9      Canada  Langley 2017-06-02 22:27:29
ID4  2.0647254234E10    Canada  Toronto 2017-06-02 22:22:49
ID5  2.0647254234E10    Canada  Toronto 2017-06-02 22:22:12
ID6  2.0647254234E10    Canada  Toronto 2017-06-02 22:21:20
```

I am able to generate one UUID4 ID using random generator for all the records, but I need to generate ofcourse separate UUIDs for all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Generate random value" step to create a column with a type "Universally Unique Identifier type 4(UUID4)".

Comment: Yes I did, but then I get same random value corresponding to all the rows, which is not whats desired.

Comment: That's weird. This step supposed to generate a unique id per row. This is exactly what happens if I connect "Table Input" (a select statement) with "Generate random value" step in the transformation flow. Do you have any intermediate steps between?

Comment: Got it now, I was using it the wrong way, I was making use of Join rows option. Its working as expected now.